# crispy form field type attribute ignored

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I am trying to use crispy forms in my django app and I can not seem to get the type attribute to set on a field.

```
#forms.py
class ReminderForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.helper=FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset('Reminder',
                Row(
                    Div(Field('message'),css_class="col"),
                    ),
                Row(
                    Div(Field('messagetype'),css_class="col-md-6"),
                    Div(Field('account'),css_class="col-md-6"),
                    ),
                Row(
                    Div(Field('reminddate',type="date"),css_class="col-md-6"),
                    Div(Field('duedate', type="date"),css_class="col-md-6"),
                    ),
                
            )  
        )

    class Meta:
        model=Reminder
        exclude=['sentdate','confirmdate','completedate']
```

my modal form

```
{% load cms_tags crispy_forms_tags %}

<div class="modal fade" id="{{formid}}" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form >
        {% crispy form %}
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

rendered html for the inputs below show reminddate and duedate style with type="text"

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <form>
 <fieldset> <legend>Reminder</legend> <div class="form-row "> <div class="col"> <div id="div_id_message" class="form-group"> <label for="id_message" class="">
                Message
            </label> <div class=""> <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="10" class="textarea form-control" id="id_message"></textarea> </div> </div> </div>

</div>
<div class="form-row "> <div class="col-md-6"> <div id="div_id_messagetype" class="form-group"> <label for="id_messagetype" class="">
                Messagetype
            </label> <div class=""> <select name="messagetype" class="select form-control" id="id_messagetype"> <option value="">---------</option> <option value="email">Email</option> <option value="sms">Text Message</option> <option value="internal">Internal Website</option>

</select> </div> </div> </div>
<div class="col-md-6"> <div id="div_id_account" class="form-group"> <label for="id_account" class="">
                Account
            </label> <div class=""> <select name="account" class="select form-control" id="id_account"> <option value="" selected="">---------</option> <option value="4">jim.pm</option> <option value="2">joe.sp</option> <option value="3">sally.om</option> <option value="1">sparrow</option>

</select> </div> </div> </div>

</div>
<div class="form-row "> <div class="col-md-6"> <div id="div_id_reminddate" class="form-group"> <label for="id_reminddate" class=" requiredField">
                Reminddate<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class=""> <input type="text" name="reminddate" class="datetimeinput form-control" required="" id="id_reminddate"> </div> </div> </div>
<div class="col-md-6"> <div id="div_id_duedate" class="form-group"> <label for="id_duedate" class=" requiredField">
                Duedate<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class=""> <input type="text" name="duedate" class="datetimeinput form-control" required="" id="id_duedate"> </div> </div> </div>

</div> </fieldset> </form>

        
      </div>
```

[rendred form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHaWS.png)

How do I correctly set the type attribute?  Other attributes(custom attributes) work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Martin Beran pointed me in the right direction.  Since I am trying to stay with the {% crispy form %} method... I found that using the widgets override in the Meta class provided what I needed!

```
    class Meta:
        model=Reminder
        exclude=['sentdate','confirmdate','completedate']
        widgets = {
            'reminddate': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'}),
            'duedate': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'})
        }
```

[Form with bootstrap date control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3RNS.png)

Comment: I used that too, but there was a problem, probably with a `SplitDateTimeWidget`, that's why I made the template filter

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you want type=date, that's a tricky one... you should make your own widget then, but if you are lazy, like me, you make a workaround with a template filter:

```py
from django import forms
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def set_input_type(field, field_type=None):
  if field_type:
    pass
  elif isinstance(field.field.widget, forms.DateInput):
    field_type = 'date'
  elif isinstance(field.field.widget, forms.TimeInput):
    field_type = 'time'
  elif isinstance(field.field.widget, forms.SplitDateTimeWidget):
    for subfield in field.field.widget.widgets:
      if isinstance(subfield, forms.DateInput):
        subfield.input_type = 'date'
      elif isinstance(subfield, forms.TimeInput):
        subfield.input_type = 'time'
  elif isinstance(field.field.widget, forms.DateTimeInput):
    # field_type = 'datetime-local'  # can't work with passing/returning ISO format
    # field_type = 'datetime'  # is deprecated, doesn't work in many browsers
    # use widget=forms.SplitDateTimeWidget() instead
    pass

  if field_type:
    field.field.widget.input_type = field_type

  return field
```

so you can change the type in template like

```
{{ form.dt|set_input_type:'date' }}
```

but ofc if you use just `{% crispy form %}`, you have to go the first (preferable) way and make your own widget :)

also another way is to use JS, like `$('#id_reminddate').attr('type', 'date');`

btw they probably use type=text, because type=date is ugly in desktop browsers, so you use some JS library like jqueryui for callendars

Comment: Can you clarify?  I am not seeing how the widget addresses being able to set html tag attributes specifically with a cripsy form layout. The end goal is to leverage bootstrap4 for display.

Comment: sry, I changed my answer, I didnt get you right before

Comment: the widget answer pointed me in the right direction, but I only needed the existing Meta widgets override.  See full answer